# Is there a way to make it so that I don’t get a hamburger menu, but rather a desktop style nav, when resizing to a mobile size

Tags: menus, navigation

I only have a few menus in my nav, and I don’t think a hamburger menu has the appropriate look for my mobile site.

Anyway to force it to look like it does on the desktop?

Comment: This depends entirely on your theme. You will need to ask the theme author.

Comment: You need some changes in css.
I can help me.